# Инициализация переменной в конструкторе

Tags: java, инициализация

Есть такой класс:

```
public class Game implements Screen {

    private World world;
    private Renderer renderer;

    public Game() {         
        world = new World();
        renderer = new Renderer(world);
    }
}
```

Почему переменные инициализируются внутри конструктора, а не в месте их создания?

Например, можно просто написать:

```
private World world = new World();
```

В чем отличие таких способов инициализации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Плюсы** использования инициализации переменной в строке с её объявлением:

1. Если имеется несколько конструкторов, то это позволяет избежать необходимости инициализировать переменную в каждом из конструкторов.
2. При использовании анонимных классов нет возможности создавать их конструкторы - соответственно, инициализировать `final` поля класса можно только с помощью инициализации при объявлении и блока инициализации объекта.

**Минусы** такого использования:

1. Отсутствует возможность обработки исключений при инициализации.
2. Отсутствует возможность проведения сколько-либо сложных вычислений (например, использование цикла `for`) при инициализации. В этом случае придётся воспользоваться конструктором или блоком инициализации объекта.

Answer (score 2):

"не в месте их создания" - не создания, a декларации

Компилятор не пропустит конструкцию

```
private Renderer renderer = new Renderer(world);
```

так как в правой части деклараций-назначений инстанс-члены класса не доступны/не готовы для использования.

Comment: Отчего же не пропустит? `renderer` объявляется после `world`, так что конструкция `private World world = new World(); private Renderer renderer = new Renderer(world);` вполне валидная.